# Representing graph colouring as a propositional formula?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

1. Explain how to encode with a propositional formula the conditions for $G$ to have a $k$-coloring.
   You are only asked to give a principle, not an explicit formula.
   Consider the following graph $G$ with $V = \{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5\}$ 
   and $E = \{(v_1, v_2), (v_2, v_3), (v_3, v_4), (v_4, v_5), (v_5, v_1), (v_1, v_3)\}$.
2. Express as a propositional formula $P_2$ the fact that the above graph has a 2-coloring.
3. Express as a propositional formula $P_3$ the fact that the above graph has a 3-coloring.

How would I go about showing this? I'm just confused if I should just brute force my way through this question... and also how would I represent the different colours?

Comment: What primitives are you allowed to use?

Comment: "Let G be an undirected graph. We denote by V the set of its vertices and by E that of its edges. Let
n be the number of elements in V .
A ”graph coloring” signs a color to each vertex, such that if two vertices are connected, then they
have a different color. A graph coloring using at most k colors is called a k-coloring. The Graph
Coloring Problem asks whether a k-coloring for G exists."

Comment: You've given the edges as ordered pairs, which would make the graph directed. If that was intentional, please use the term "directed graph".

Comment: My mistake. It's an introductory course and ordered pairs are used for both directed and undirected edges (which makes me cringe, but is commonplace here) But the graph is very much undirected

Comment: If the edges are meant to be undirected, then it would be best to use set brackets, or the common notation $v_1v_2$.

Comment: In the first part, are you supposed to find a formula which is valid for all graphs or just the given graph? I believe the former is impossible without quantification.

Comment: To begin with, how could you express "the colour of $v_1v_2$ is not the same as that of $v_2v_3$"?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: It's the vertices being colored, not the edges.

Comment: It sounds strange to want a _propositional_ formula for this. I can readily imagine a propositional formula for "is such-and-such a valid $k$-coloring?", or a (pure) first-order formula for "does this have a valid $k$-coloring?" but how would what's being asked for here even work? What are the propositional variables?

Comment: Or are we asking for a propositional formula that is _satisfiable_ iff the graph has a $k$-coloring?

Comment: @HenningMakholm OK, but that still leaves the question how to express "the color of $v_1$ is not the same as the colour of $v_2$" when it is still not clear what the language even is

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Agreed.

Comment: I can see how I can represent $P_2$ as a propositional formula, but not really how I can represent $P_3$